Why "Lost connection to RDP Server" on Ubuntu 24.04 using Remmina
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 on both computers with both on same network. RDP Server on the host is configured using standard Ubuntu Settings app: both Remote Desktop Sharing & Remote Control set. Hostname is Laptop with Port 3389. Port 3389 has Port Forwarding for 3389 on Router to the appropriate reserved DHCP ip address. I'm trying to connect using Remmina. Any ideas please?
